# External non-partitioned Hive table shows 0 records even if parquet file has data, when read using spark.read.parquet it shows correct data

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have an external non-partitioned hive table created on Azure DataBricks.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE reference.date_file(
  `date_init` string,
  `trade_date_minus_5` string,
  `trade_date_minus_4` string,
  `trade_date_minus_3` string,
  `trade_date_minus_2` string,
  `trade_date_minus_1` string,
  `trade_date` string,
  `trade_date_plus_1` string,
  `trade_date_plus_2` string,
  `trade_date_plus_3` string,
  `trade_date_plus_4` string,
  `trade_date_plus_5` string)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/mnt/data/reference/data/DATE_FILE'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'parquet.compress'='SNAPPY'
)
```

It also has parquet file present in the location which I copied from other location.

When I do `select * from reference.date_file` it returns 0 results even if data/records are present.

The same file when I do...

```
val temp = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/data/reference/data/DATE_FILE")
temp.show()
```

... returns the records.

Can someone please help what can be the issue here?

Comment: You might need to run MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name; and then query the table again it looks hive metastore is not updated.

Comment: This is not partitioned table. MSCK REPAIR works only on partitioned tables. Tried it. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved.

I simply changed the location to some other location, re-created the table, restored the original location, recreated the table. And it started showing the data. May be there was some issue with the hive metadata. Changing the location and restoring corrected the metadata I guess.